# Raw mongodb query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Rails/Mongoid app that displays data client-side using highcharts. Right now, to pass the data to Javascript, I use a Mongoid query and Rails' as_json/to_json in the template file. This seems very inefficient to me because the json data has to be parsed into ruby structures, and then re-converted to JSON. This is okay when there is a small amount of data, but in my case, there can be a lot.

So my question is, how can I do a raw mongodb query, and just write the output directly to the Rails response buffer without going through Ruby JSON serialization/deserialization?

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in MongoDB is stored in BSON, which is not JSON.
The ruby driver does deserialization (BSON::BSON_CODER.deserialize) in read_documents method. If you'd like to roll your own BSON-to-JSON, you'll need your implementation of BSON::BSON_coder.deserialize, and, probably, rewrite more parts in mongo-ruby driver.
If, however, this is a overhead that's acceptable, then you'll just subclass ActionController::Metal and do something like this:

```
class ChartController < ActionController::Metal
  def chart
    res = fetch_data_from_mongodb
    self.content_type = 'application/json'
    self.response_body = res.to_json
  end
end
```

Another alternative might be using the MongoDB's [REST](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-SimpleRESTInterface) HTTP interface, which provides JSON. But you'll have to have some access control in your application, and, basically, proxy requests.